# Does Using goto to Escape Control Structures Ever Produce Different Assembly?

Tags: c++, c, conditional-statements, goto, control-structure

There is a lot of debate about the `goto` command, this question is not about the rightness or wrongness of its use, but more simply a question of whether it ever actually creates different assembly.

I'm specifically looking at Visual Studio 2013, but an example in any compiler would be wonderful.

[Bjarne Stroustrup states](https://books.google.com/books?id=PSUNAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA238#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> The scope of a label is the function it is in (§6.3.4). This implies that you can use `goto` to jump into and out of blocks. The only restriction is that you cannot jump past an initializer or an exception handler (§13.5).
>   One to the few sensible uses of `goto` in ordinary code is to break out from a nested loop or `switch`-statement.

**My question then: Is there any instance in which `goto` still produces different assembly than what can already be accomplished by use of other control structures?**

For example, this produces identical assembly:

```
auto r = rand();
auto a = 0;

for(auto i = rand(); i > 0; --i){
    switch(r){
    case 1:
        ++sum;
        goto END;
    case default:
        sum += rand();
        break;
    }
}
sum++;
END:
```

To this non-`goto` code:

```
auto r = rand();
auto b = false;
auto a = 0;

for(auto i = rand(); i > 0; --i){
    switch(r){
    case 1:
        ++sum;
        b = true;
        break;
    case default:
        sum += rand();
        break;
    }
    if(b)break;
}

if(!b)sum++;
```

Comment: Please clarify what "different assembly" is compared to.

Comment: According to the GCC documentation on its internals, it actually won't matter.  GCC already converts the control structures into goto statements and its branch analysis will resolve any fancy tricks you may have used.

Comment: Please give example of the code; edit your post and **NOT AS A COMMENT**.  I'm looking for clarification on *"...compiler will not allow me to jump out of scope..."*

Comment: @wallyk I've added an example does that clarify?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have added an example of what I'm trying to say, and I've clarified the statement in question to: "Since the compiler will not allow me to jump into another function the only thing goto can be used for is a control structure." Is the question still unclear now?

Comment: The bias against goto isn't because of optimizations and assembly, but because it makes it harder for the humans reading the code to track the flow logically if it's overused.

Comment: @Donnie Right, I understand that. This isn't a question about good coding practices though, this is a question about whether the `goto` command can create assembly that I cannot replicate with other control structures.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say "no".  When you get down to the assembly its all just compares and jumps.  Higher level structures all distill down to goto eventually.

Comment: @Donnie From what I've seen I agree with that. What I was hoping for was a counter example, so that I could see `goto` as more important than something maintained for backwards compatibility.

Comment: You're thinking about it the wrong way though, it's for code readability (or the lack of it) that you pick various control structures, not because of the generated assembly.  Your modern optimizer isn't going to typically translate your code directly into assembly anyways.

Comment: @Donnie I'm with you. (As I believe Bjarne Stroustrup is from my latest edit.) This was a curiosity question though. I'd like to know if there is the possibility of different assembly being generated. (Or machine code or whatever.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my experience: I once had a bit of code that was *extremely* time critical. And it had a loop that iterated on average zero times (while (condition) ...) and the condition was almost always false. The compiler insisted on loop optimisations, moving things outside the loop - even when the loop wasn't executed at all, therefore slowing it down.

I tried to rewrite the loop using goto, hoping to confuse the optimiser enough to give up on optimising the code, and failed. gcc and clang optimise depending on the actual control flow, not depending on what C or C++ code you use.

Comment: Off-topic but `__builtin_expect` is your friend.

Comment: If you could somehow obtain a minimal example of said code that would make an amazing answer, though I understand that may not be possible.

Comment: @doynax:  From [_builtin_expect's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html): **In general, you should prefer to use actual profile feedback for this (-fprofile-arcs), as *programmers are notoriously bad* at predicting how their programs actually perform.**

Comment: @wallyk gnu is also notoriously bad at predicting how clever other users are compared to themselves

Comment: @SteveCox:  That seems like it would be a worthy subject for expansion.  Maybe you could ask a question (How well does gnu predict cleverness?) and answer it?

Comment: Did you try rewriting your loop as `if (condition) {initial_stuff; do {interior_stuff;} while (condition);}`?